# scons: *** [libserf-1.dll] Error 1120 when Building Apache Serf

Tags: apache, build

I Have tried to build the Apache Serf with SCons build system https://github.com/fcharlie/serf. I have used the proper Apr, Apr-Util, and Openssl for serf build. When executing the following command "scons APR=C:\Serf\AprApu APU=C:\Serf\AprApu OPENSSL=C:\Serf\OpenSSL PREFIX=C:\Serf\serf-1.3.9", I got the following Errors.

> libserf-1.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 143 unresolved externals
>   scons: *** [libserf-1.dll] Error 1120
>   scons: building terminated because of error

How to Resolve this?

Please find the Screenshot of the Error Details:

[image: Please find the Screenshot of the Error Details]